# How to autofill values

Tags: sas

I wanna to fill the corresponding Group information for the same ID line.

e.g. ID=1001 will have Group=A, two are missing.
SInce I have lots of observations, not efficient to do that by hand.

Could you please suggest a way that I can use in SAS?

[image]

Comment: Is the image one of a data set view, or of output from say `Proc REPORT` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Track the last non-missing group value in a retained variable.  Apply the tracked value when group value is missing.

Example:

```
data have;
input group $ id;
datalines;
A 1
A 1
. 1
. 1
B 2
B 2
. 2
. 2
C 3
C 3
. 3
. 3
;
data want(drop=fill);
  set have;

  if not missing(group) then
    fill=group;
  else
    group=fill;

  retain fill;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works!                                                                            How does it know to stop tracking or track a new group value when it encountering "B"? And not remembering "A".

Comment: @Jingxin, It is the `retain` statement who really matters. Look at the `if not missing(group) then ...`, it is 'B' in row 5, so SAS executes `fill = group`, which give `fill` the value of `group`, that's 'B'. In row 6, `group` is 'B', it is not missing so SAS executes `fill = group` again. In row 7, `group` is missing so SAS executes 'group = fill', as fill is retained, `group` is gived the retaind value of  `fill`, that is 'B'.